# How do you create a button in HTML for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im making a small form for an index page.

```
@model MarketPlace.Models.Download
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Downloads", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EMail)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EMail, new { @class = "form-control round-input", @style = "width:200px" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reference)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Reference, new {@class = "form-control round-input", @style = "width:200px"})</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products)</td>
    <td>@Html.Buttonorsomething
}
```

I thought there would have been a `@Html.Button or something, and I searched on Google, but apparently they didn't add one.

My question is, how can I make a button?

edit: Please note, I've been using ASP.NET MVC for a very short time now, please forgive me for this silly question!

Comment: simply include pure html button it will work

Comment: If you need helper - look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955571/theres-no-html-button

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955571/theres-no-html-button). It has some discussion why there is no `@Html.Button` and how you can create custom html heler to render a `button`.

Comment: Best example from our own Microsoft (www.asp.net) Link: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search

Answer (score 18):

simply include pure html button it will work

like

```
<input type="button" value="Create" />
```

if you want a HTML button that will call your MVC controler's action method then .
try this

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "User")'" />
```

Note : The best practice is to avoid obtrusive Javascript, you can have it as a separate `onclick` method.

Update :

If you really want a helper then you can create a custom helper class type of `MvcHtmlString`

a good example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067874/looking-for-a-html-submitbutton-helper-that-would-accept-class-attributes-in-mvc)

Comment: Don't use obtrusive JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use HTML in Razor:

```
<input type="submit" />
<input type="button" />
```

There isn't an helper for every HTML element.