# Input Submit Button - Html.buttonfor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I am a bit new to mvc razor and building websites (front and backend). The break down is, I need a button that has a value stored in it be sent to the controller/model. Something similar to html boxtextfor. I have tried giving boxtextfor attributes similar to an input submit button, but it doesn't like that. I have tested the button using javascript and it does have the value within each individual button (# of buttons are dynamic based on previous submit).

I have seen posts like this but I am unsure how to add these to my controller or model so my index page can call it. My model is linked to my index page so I guess I could link these methods in my model.

[There's no @Html.Button !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955571/theres-no-html-button)

(tried this, but it needs to be linked to my model. A simple button doesn't work.)
[Looking for a Html.SubmitButton helper that would accept class attributes in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067874/looking-for-a-html-submitbutton-helper-that-would-accept-class-attributes-in-mvc)

I currently don't have access to my code in question. The button needs to be an input submit to go to [HTTPPOST]. However, if you need any more information please let me know.

Thank you for your time,

HtmlNooby

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='submitValue'>` or `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.submitValue)` - is there a reason it needs to be on the button?  Do you have multiple buttons?

Comment: Yeah, I am updating an old system that is PHP and the previous page and users are used to the buttons. So, I am recreating the page using MVC razor to be compatible with the new website.

Thanks for the suggestion! I will work on it tomorrow.

Comment: If you have multiple buttons, you can determine which butt caused the submit without a hidden field, using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111222/2181514 - no doubt it can be extended to add additional information to a single button, so not reliant on multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping a button with the following. This creates binds each individual button with the given item from an array. Kind of acts like a buttonfor if you will.

```
Foreach item in array{
  @using(Html.BeginForm(…)
  {
    <button class=input value=item>item</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't put a beginform inside a loop like this. Just have the various buttons in one form.